# Why sensors value is different in different android devices?

Tags: android

Why accelerometer value is different in different devices? as well the proximity value of my device is 0 and 1 but another device proximity value is 3 to 8 why these are happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Android Compatibility Definition Document for Android 6.0 - section 7.3.8 - the only MUST requirement for the Proximity Sensor is at least 1 bit accuracy.

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf