# onPause() getting detected on Samsung devices because of Proximity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, samsung-mobile

I am using a `MediaPlayer` to play Media and I stop it on `onPause()` (home button clicked, back, lock etc.), but on Samsung devices it is also called when they sense proximity i.e. when I want to hear the music on earpiece, it will call `onPause()` and the music stops. What is the best way to handle this case? I have 2 options:

1. Don't stop `MediaPlayer` on `onPause()` and detect a) onBackPressed(), b) Home button click, and c) lock screen. But I am not able to detect b) and c). Seems it is not allowed anymore.
2. **Stop** `MediaPlayer` on `onPause()`, but with some condition so that Samsung devices are also handled. The problem is I don't know what condition would be best.

Has anyone faced this? What would be the best solution?

Comment: hi..i had the same problem, [this could help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318649/android-proximity-sensor-issue-only-in-samsung-devices/37508973#37508973)

Comment: @user2450263 Haven't gone through the link. But would I need to implement all 3 points, or 1 of them?

Comment: you could use the first one..move your functions from onPause()