# Samsung proximity sensor issue with voip calling

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, proximitysensor

I am using portsip sdk to make voip calls via internet. It works fine for all other phones but Samsung for which the proximity sensor makes the screen flicker. 
The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318649/android-proximity-sensor-issue-only-in-samsung-devices) is correct and I do recieve call back in onpause() repeatedly when the sensor is registered but the solution given doesnot work with me.

Please look into. Any help will be appreciated.